# Efficient algorithm to search minimum of function with noise

Tags: optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Assume I want to find the mimimum of some function $f(x)$
but I can only compute $$f(x) + \varepsilon,$$ where $\varepsilon$ is some random variable with mean 0. With enough computation power I can shrink the variance of $\varepsilon$, but that's costly.

Standard gradient descent algorithms do not work, because numeric finite-difference approximations of the gradient are really bad (+unstable) with the noise.

My parameter space is fairly small so that grid-search is an option, but it assume there are better ways. What are standard approaches to such problems?

**Background**: In each function evaluation I have to simulate several repetitons of a random process. I am using this for a simulated method of moments estimation.

Comment: If the frequency spectrum of the noise is not entirely within the frequency spectrum of the function applying a digital filter may be an option. However simple and computationally efficient time domain digital filters for example are likely to introduce other errors like phase shifting the minimum of the function with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here via a search:

I found two workable solutions.

- Bayesian Model Based optimization can help here (in `R`, use `mlrMBO`). But it wasn't working very well for me (it was slow and hard to adapt to my application).
- I ended up coding up a variant of [Simulated Annealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing), which is usually espacially usefull for high-dimensional spaces with multiple local optima, But it turned out to also be super efficient for my simple problem with noise. It is also straightforward to increase the number of function evaluations (to reduce noise) the closer we move to the end.